# Stop service belonging to another application on Android

Tags: android, service, root

How to stop service belonging to another application on Android? Service is started with START_STICKY so if I kill it's process it gets restarted after few seconds. 
Any ideas (incl. those that needs root access) are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to force stop a package until it is explicitly started again by another package (e.g. opened from launcher). This can be done by running the following command as root:

```
am force-stop package_name_to_stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one way I found it stop service all time when it come back. You can check per few seconds list of running services ( ActivityManager.getRunningServices(int) ) and kill the service you want to kill every time when it found there.